# Label on axis of chart by group, is it possible with Highcharts?

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I'm new to highcharts and I want to know if something like this is possible: http://img824.imageshack.us/img824/6537/sample1w.png

I haven't found anything similar in the showcase they provide so I thought someone more experienced could let me know how to accomplish this.

Thank you very much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use bar chart, and use `groupPadding` http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#plotOptions.bar.groupPadding to set distance between groups of bars.

http://jsfiddle.net/7fvEX/

To add text, above one of group, you can use Renderer: http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#Renderer.text()